# X axis label formatting in Shinobi charts

Tags: ios, shinobi

I have a chart of name versus age, where name is on the x axis and value on Y axis.
The problem is the names are getting overlapped on the x axis which do not look good.

I could not find any formatting for showing truncated name values on x axis and complete as we zoom in.

Is there any way to show names with ellipses or other formatting where the names will not overlap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `alterTickMark:` method on `SChartDelegate` allows you to modify a `tickMark` (and its corresponding `tickLabel`) before they are added to the axis.

You could potentially check the `axisRange` in this step, and decide if the `range.span` is small enough that you could display labels truncated or in full.

E.g.

```
-(void)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart alterTickMark:(SChartTickMark *)tickMark beforeAddingToAxis:(SChartAxis *)axis
{
    if (!axis.isXAxis)
        return;

    if ([axis.axisRange.span doubleValue] > 5)
    {
        NSString *shortText = [tickMark.tickLabel.text substringToIndex:3];
        tickMark.tickLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...", shortText];

        //Resize, but maintain centering
        CGPoint center = tickMark.tickLabel.center;
        [tickMark.tickLabel sizeToFit];
        tickMark.tickLabel.center = center;
    }
}
```

As full disclosure, I work for ShinobiControls.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to adjust tick label width in column series and zooming is enabled (which makes more space for label after zoom gesture), just implement SChart delegate method:

```
- (void)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart alterTickMark:(SChartTickMark *)tickMark beforeAddingToAxis:(SChartAxis *)axis
{
    if (axis.isXAxis) {
        // Adjusting tickmark labels
        UILabel *label = [tickMark tickLabel];

        CGFloat maxLabelWidth = axis.axisFrame.size.width / [axis.axisRange.span floatValue];
        CGRect labelFrame = label.frame;
        labelFrame.size.width = maxLabelWidth;

        [label setFrame:labelFrame];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the longestLabelStringOn delegate method. Example:

```
func sChart(_ chart: ShinobiChart, longestLabelStringOn axis: SChartAxis) -> String? {
        if axis == chart.xAxis{
            return "Longest Possible String"
        }
        else{
            return ""
        }
    }
```